# Getting a error in node.js using subString

Tags: node.js

Hi there all this is my first question on here so i hope its ok

i am trying to get my code to get the content between two , , , in this example i need to get prestons

Batehaven Cl, Prestons NSW 2170, Australia

i have tried this code

```
var country = getCountry(data.results[0]['address_components']);
var address = data.results[3]['formatted_address'];
var suburb = address;

suburb = suburb.subString(suburb.indexOf(",")+1, suburb.lastIndexOf(","));


  console.log(address);
  console.log(suburb);
```

but i am getting a error Unhandled rejection TypeError: suburb.subString is not a function

could someone please let me now what silly mistake i have made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript methods are case sensitive try **[substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)** to get `Cabramatta West` a two-word example of a suburb i.e. the below code will also work for retrieving `Prestons` in your own example:

```js
let address = "John St, Cabramatta West NSW 2166, Australia"
let suburb = address

suburb = suburb.substring(suburb.indexOf(',') + 1, suburb.lastIndexOf(','))

let states = ["TAS", "QLD", "VIC", "NSW", "SA", "WA"]
let positionOfState = -1
for (let i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
  if (address.indexOf(states[i]) != -1) {
    positionOfState = suburb.indexOf(states[i])
    break;
  }
}
suburb = suburb.substring(1, positionOfState) // 1 is to skip the space at the start

console.log(`address -> ${address}`)
console.log(`suburb -> ${suburb}`)
```

Comment: ok i dont know if we can but i just got a issues when the Suburb is 2 words

Comment: at the moment we are only doing aus so how would i do this

Comment: Updated answer with an example that has two words for its suburb.

Comment: thanks mate for some reason when i put the code in it will work in the scrips and show in the console but it stops handing the results to the response.jason

Comment: Print out the JSON object to make sure it is the same as the string in the console. It should work if it doesn't ask another question with all the relevant code from it, and what the JSON looks like exactly.